# replace last number of string with another number with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I store an image URL in a variable, and what I would like to do is swap the number right after the last underscore with 21. I know it'd be done with regex, but could someone give me a hand, not sure how I'd do it exactly.

so this:

```
var imgUrl = http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/hbeu50274754_001_10
```

would become this:

```
imgUrl = http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/hbeu50274754_001_21
```

Thanks!

Comment: replace `\d+$` with `21` . or do splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [**`String.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which accepts a regular expression as the search parameter:

```
var imgUrl = "http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/hbeu50274754_001_10";
imgUrl = imgUrl.replace(/\d+$/, 21);
// "http://images.domain.com/is/image/boss/hbeu50274754_001_21"
```